# Join data from two tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables.

Table 1

```
id      date      block value

100 2017-02-01     1      10
101 2017-02-02     2      20
102 2017-02-01     1      30
103 2017-02-02     1      40
```

Table 2

```
number  date        no       data

10    2017-02-01     1      50
11    2017-02-02     2      60
12    2017-02-01     1      70
13    2017-02-02     1      80
```

I need an output in date:
for select 2017-02-01

```
id      date      block value  number  date        no       data

100 2017-02-01     1      10    10    2017-02-01     1      50
102 2017-02-01     1      30    12    2017-02-01     1      70
```

How can I do that?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Please post the code that you had tried. Refer the article https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before posting questions

Comment: you have to use group by for merging two table

Comment: As @Axalix queries show us what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

```
select table1.*,table2.number,table2.date date2 
,table2.no ,table2.data
from table1,table2
where table1.date=table2.date2
```

Comment: Please let him show what he has done posting a direct code won't make him learn anything except copy pasting.

Comment: While this might answer the question, please add a short description of what your command does and why it solves the initial problem.

Comment: joining two table with a same column is not possible.you should rename a column in joining result.table1 and table 2 have date and after join is conflict and error will occured.I change date to date2 for table2

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.